# Customizing Risk Form in Project Server 2013

Tags: ms-project-server-2013

I have created some custom columns for the Risk List. I am able to add these column to the default view but When I click on the New Item Link in the Project Risks, I am still getting some unwanted default columns. For the Form that loads on Clicking the "New Item" Link on the risks page on a project site. 
Can we edit that form from Customize the Form on the list settings.

Will this impact the existing risk synchronization mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide those column in New/edit item, just edit its content type (**Project Site Risk**) and change it status to **Hidden (Will not appear in forms)**